# How to prevent plugged-in vacuum cleaner cord from getting tangled?

Tags: cleaning, organization, cables, office, house-cleaning

I'm searching for a lifehack that will help prevent a plugged-in vacuum cleaner cord from getting all tangled up.

[image: tangled cord]

The vacuum cleaner cannot be easily unplugged, and multiple people use it.

The best solution I have so far is for everyone to be mindful about how they vacuum, and try to make as many turns in one direction as the other.  But that's easier said than done.

Is there a better, more flexible, solution?

If not, I'm open to answers describing how to untangle the cord without unplugging it or holding the vacuum cleaner up and spinning it around dozens of times (and hopefully guessing the right direction!).

Comment: Am I getting this right: you want to avoid unplugging it because the socket isn’t really reachable, or what exactly is the reason for this restriction?

Comment: @Stephie Correct, the outlet is not easily accessible.

Comment: You can untangle by pirouetting the vacuum cleaner but it is only a temporary solution, as it is likely to tangle again in use.

Answer (score 6):

If a non-accessible power outlet is the only option you have, I recommend you invest in a short extension cord, just long enough to reach from the original outlet to the floor (to allow the plugged end to lay on the floor instead of hanging and putting unnecessary stress on the original outlet). You can look into premade cords or craft exactly the preferred length with a piece of cable and two end pieces. For more details on that, ask your hardware store or our sister site [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com).

Then you can simply unplug the vacuum cleaner when you need to untangle the cord and plug it back in as needed.

Bonus: You are free to move the vacuum to other places that you previously couldn’t reach, e.g. storing it out of sight or using it on another floor. You could even “hide” the permanent section a bit by using a white instead of a black extension.

Answer (score 1):

Use a heatgun (on its lowest setting) or hairdryer to heat the wire’s rubber insulation, then tug it to straighten it before it cools down.

Rubber has some shape retention; this happens in part because your vacuum has been hot when you return the wire to its coil, and in part because rubber is crappy.

To avoid this happening again, let the vacuum cool down for 10 minutes before coiling it. Use a figure-8 winding pattern if you never want the nuisance again.

See: http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/seriouslyscience/2014/06/18/scientific-explanation-earphones-always-tangled/